# Is RESTful webservices with Ajax ,Json,javascript and jquery alternative of JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, rest

I have perception that there is no or very less need of jsp if we use RESTful with ajax call and json.

1. We can update views using Javascript or jquery.
2. Do we need JSP in this case?
3. I am using jsp for session management only.

Do we need jsp only for session management in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JSPs to have a HttpSession, if you manage your REST services with servlets or Spring MVC. So, the answer to your question, is no.

However, a template framework like JSP or FreeMarker is still useful in case you want to use tags that are resolved on the server.